# Made a trip to US, left before original return ticket, can I make another trip and use my original return ticket?

Tags: air-travel

The title is hopefully self-explanatory, but I'll provide more details.

I had a round-trip flight from Canada to the US booked for a three month visit (Oct through Dec), but had a family member become ill two weeks into the trip and I returned by bus (only cheap next-day option) back to Canada. My family member's health complication stabilized and is doing well, so I would like to complete my trip. My question is: a) Can I still use the return ticket?, and b) Does it count as a return ticket when crossing the border/will the return to Canada and coming back throw any red flags?

Thanks.

Comment: If you took the flight from Canada to the USA, you can use the return ticket from the USA to Canada.

Comment: Yes. People do this all the time.

Answer (score 3):

A) it does. You're taking your original trip back. What you do between arriving and departing does not matter.

B) that is not a problem. What matters is that you have the intent to leave. You obviously do as you have a ticket. If anyone does ask questions, tell them the truth.